# _gwt$exception : Cannot read property 'uuid' of undefined

Tags: cordova, mgwt

I am working on a mgwt-phonegap application.

I am using this code:

```
final PhoneGap phoneGap = GWT.create(PhoneGap.class);
phoneGap.addHandler(new PhoneGapAvailableHandler() {

@Override        
public void onPhoneGapAvailable(PhoneGapAvailableEvent event) {               
//start your app - phonegap is ready
Window.alert("phonegap is ready");        
}});

phoneGap.addHandler(new PhoneGapTimeoutHandler() {        
@Override        
public void onPhoneGapTimeout(PhoneGapTimeoutEvent event) {                
//can not start phonegap - something is for with your setup 
Window.alert("can not start phonegap");               
}});
phoneGap.initializePhoneGap();
```

When I am using the compiled code from the target folder, to phonegap i.e assets/www folder and running the phonegap application. It is giving me this error:

```
_gwt$exception : Cannot read property 'uuid' of undefined
```

This is the script I am using on index.html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="MyApplication/MyApplication.nocache.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", (function() {
                cordova.available = true;
            }), false);
```

This particular code is catching this exception:

```
GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

     @Override
     public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
     // TODO put in your own meaninful handler
     Window.alert("uncaught: " + e.getMessage());
     e.printStackTrace();

     }
     });
```

Comment: This issue got solved. It was because I had not included the Device plugin into my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to elaborate more:

Add device plugin just as mentioned below. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_device_device.md.html

Regards,
Sandip